# DBA vs ALL views performance

Tags: oracle

I'd like to know if there is some performance advantage of using DBA_ catalog views over ALL_ views for querying database metadata and in which situations (if any) this advantage would manifest.

Comment: test it and see it for yourself, but in the docs we do indicate that DBA_ views are faster - using the ALL views involves a check to see what you have access to, that's an extra step.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle dictionary is slow so the general rule of thumb is *not to use* dictionary in performance critical code. If you terribly need metadata in your application, you can create materialized view based on dictionary tables and refresh it manually after executing DDL. Of course, not every change in dictionary is made by user DDL, but I don't know what kind of meatadata exactly you need.

As for difference in ALL_ and DBA_ views I believe it is marginal. For obvious reasons, `DBA_` views have more data than `ALL_` views. In each case you can try to obtain DDL for them using DBMS_METADATA package.

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'ALL_TABLES', 'SYS')
from dual
```

I will not attach the output since it's pretty verbose and useless. In case of `ALL_TABLES` list of tables used in `FROM` is the same. Since you access much the same data, perform same joins and just filter rows a bit differently, performance-wise the result should be about the same.